# Which is better? Rashba effect or Dresselhaus effect?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, quantum-espresso, quantum-mechanics

My current research focus is on the band splitting observed in 2D perovskite. Existing literature suggests that site inversion asymmetry (SIA) may lead to the Rashba effect, while bulk inversion asymmetry (BIA) may result in the Dresselhaus effect (as referenced in 10.1038/nphys2933 and 10.1021/acsnano.5b04409). I have observed that these effects, in conjunction with spin-orbit coupling (SOC), contribute to band splitting. However, the spin textures associated with the Rashba and Dresselhaus effects are distinct from each other. It is commonly seen that both effects are present in 2D perovskites, leading to band splitting.

This leads me to pose the following query: Despite both effects contributing to band splitting, do they influence other properties of 2D perovskite in a differential manner?